# How to increment the characters when the function called for first time?

Tags: python, mysql, auto-increment

I am working on socket programming where I shown the code which I use in Python Socket and here I fetch some data from database and validating, if the data is validated it will start the function where I created the passkey.

After giving the range of 1 it will show A001 which is stored in the database, but I want it to be incremented that is A002 when the function runs for the 2nd client.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql 
mydb1=mysql.connect(
        user = 'rajat',
        passwd = 'rajat',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'master_database'
        )
mycursor5=mydb1.cursor()
mycursor5.execute("SELECT Version FROM form_simpleform")
obj2 = mycursor5.fetchone()
if obj2 == ('2',):
    def full_format(i):
        if i < 26 * 999:
            c,n = divmod(i,999)   # quotient c is index of letter 0-25, remainder n is 0-998
            c = chr(ord('A') + c) # compute letter
            n += 1
            return f'{c}{n:03}'
        else:
            raise OverflowError(f'limit is {26*999}')
    for X in range(1):
        print(full_format(X))
        mycursor6 = mydb1.cursor()
        sql3 = mycursor6.execute("INSERT INTO imeiserial (Passkey) VALUES ('%s')", (X))
        result = mycursor6.execute(sql3)
        mydb1.commit()
        print('data inserted into the db')
        print(mycursor6.rowcount, "record inserted.")
else:
    print('NOT A PASSKEY')
```

Comment: You basically have 2 options. If this is a single threaded application, you can introduce a global variable.  If not, and if you require data to be persistent, you can utilize Redis for incrementing key values.

Comment: In starting it is a single threaded application to see how function is going to work, but afterwards it will be multi threaded application

Comment: How can I use redis here for incrementing values

Comment: import redis; r = redis.Redis(host=<your_host>, port=<your_port>, db=<your_db>);  . And just call r.incr("my_counter", 1) on start of your function. If you need to fetch the value then, r.get("my_counter"). Of course, you need to have redis server started.

Comment: ok, I will try redis for my code.

Comment: is there is any other of doing this?